# Kernel Programming - Mutexes

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel-module

So I'm trying to use `mutex_init()`, `mutex_lock()`, `mutex_unlock()` for thread synchronization.

I am currently trying to schedule threads in a round robin fashion(but more than 1 thread could be running at a time) and I set the current state of a thread to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`, followed by waking up another thread whose PID, I have in a list.

I need to iterate over this list for my logic.

As I understand it, I need to lock this list as I access its elements, or another thread might miss a new entry while I'm making changes to it. Also, as one mutex has locked a resource, no other mutex can unlock it, until the original mutex releases it.

But, I'm still not sure if I'm locking it correctly. (I release the lock before I call `schedule()`, and re-lock after that)

I declare a mutex locally within a thread and lock the list. After my current thread locks

```
mutex_lock(&lock);
```

and I iterate over the list, till I find something(or ends if it doesn't find anything), then unlocks.

```
mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

I assume locking while I iterate is legal. I have never seen examples of this though.

Also, is it normal for the process to have a state of (`TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE`) while it holds a mutex lock?

**EDIT :** I am adding some more information based on the answer below.

It is possible my program may be run on a virtual machine with a single core. Therefore, I do not want to risk infinite polling using `spin_lock()`.

I am trying to maintain scheduling between threads that have a certain id. For example if there are 4 threads. 2 in set 'A' and 2 in set 'B'. I allow only 1 thread to run in each set. But I switch between threads in a given set. However, a thread in set 'A' should not switch to any thread in set 'B'

(I know the kernel scheduler wont be perfect, so an approximate switching will do).

My Reasoning for TASK_STATE's:

1) Initial thread that gets created is running.

2) If another thread in the same set is running (and this one hasn't executed for a given time). Set other thread to `TASK_INTERRUPTIPLE`, while calling `schedule()`; **Note:** There can be more than 2 threads in each set, but let's keep it simple by considering only 2 for now.

3) If it has executed for enough time, set this task to `TASK_INTERRUPTIPLE`, set the other task in the same set to `TASK_RUNNING`, while calling `schedule()`;

All this logic happens while I am accessing certain data structures which are locked by a (now) Global Mutex. I unlock the mutex just before I call `schedule()`, and instantly re-lock afterward. After my logic part is done, I completely unlock the mutex.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong with the approach?

Comment: "But, I'm still not sure if I'm locking it correctly." - It is you who defines "correctness" term for your program. With so little code it is difficult to say what is correct and what is not. "is it normal for the process to have a state of (`TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE`) while it holds a mutex lock?" - Yes, it is *acceptible* to hold a mutex while waiting. That is, you are better to avoid such behaviour, but nothing wrong in holding the mutex during the wait if you need that.

Comment: Re, "I declare a mutex locally." That doesn't sound good. Locking a mutex has no effect except when two or more threads attempt to lock the _same_ mutex. If "locally" means, "in a local variable," then how do other threads access the same mutex?

Comment: How about showing some code here? You're asking, "did I do it right?" but you've only given a rough description of what you are doing, and practically no description of how you are trying to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand it, I need to lock this list as I access its elements

Yes, that is true. But if you use a mutex, you're going to be really sad because a call to `lock`/`unlock` *is* a call to the scheduler. Therefore, calling it from inside the scheduler should result in deadlock. What you need to do depends on if your processor is multi-core or (the mythical) single-core. (Is this a virtual system?) On a single-core processor you can disable interrupts. On a multi-core processor, disabling interrupts is not sufficient (it only disables interrupts for that one core, and another core may still be interrupted). The simplest thing to do on a multi-core is to use a spinlock. Unlike the mutex, both of these locking mechanisms can be unlocked from different threads.

> I set the current state of a thread to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`

Is the thread being taken off the CPU? If so, it's not running, so I suspect that `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` is the wrong state. It would be helpful if you could list the possible states for me or if you could describe what the state is supposed to indicate. Because to me "`TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`" sounds like a running task.

> I declare a mutex locally within a thread and lock the list

Local mutexes are a red flag! The resource you are locking should be protected by a mutex with the same scope. If the list is global, it should have a global mutex to protect it. Threads that want to use the list must first acquire its mutex. Of course, as I already talked about, you probably want to use a different kind of locking to protect the list of ready-to-run processes.

> I assume locking while I iterate is legal

It is perfectly legal (assuming of course that your mutual exclusion scheme is bug-free). In fact, it's required. If another thread were allowed to, for example, remove a node from the list while you were reading it, you could end up dereferencing a deleted node.

> Also, is it normal for the process to have a state of `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` while it holds a mutex lock?

No, not while it holds the lock if the process is currently running on a CPU. A mutex is available to user code. If holding a mutex made the process uninterruptible, that would mean that a process could hijack the system by simply locking a mutex and never releasing it. Now, you will find that the `lock` and `unlock` functions need to be uninterruptible on a single-core processor. However, it doesn't make sense to set the state for the process because it's actually the scheduler that must not be interrupted.

Comment: I've updated my question. Could you please have a look?